# SoundCloud Widget - Close button

Tags: soundcloud

I have a number of SoundCloud widgets on a long web page (so the web page doesn't change position like, say, jump to the top when a SoundCloud file is invoked).

But, I can't find a close button for the widget, so there is potential for many widgets to be open at one time.  And it appears that if too many are open, a new one does not load the sound file. (It is neat that when a new widget is opened, any existing visible widgets are automatically paused.)

Has anyone found a way to allow the user to close a SoundCloud widget?

Answer (score 0):

In my website I just made my own button that's in the same container as the widget iframe and applied some CSS rules to it.
HTML:

```
<div id="playerContainer">
        <span id="closePlayer" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        <iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/164855780&amp;amp;color=5ab7e6&amp;amp;auto_play=true&amp;hide_related=false&amp;amp;show_comments=true&amp;amp;show_user=true&amp;amp;show_reposts=false" style="display: inline;"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#closePlayer { 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 142px;
    right: 3px;
    z-index: 999;  
}
```

JS (Includes jQuery):

```
document.getElementById('closePlayer').addEventListener('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

How it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5ej6.png

I know this was published a while ago but I just saw it, hope it'll help somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own button and use [`kill()`](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript) on whichever player you want to destroy.